# Testing CSS Transition finished in Jasmine

Tags: javascript, jquery, jasmine, jasmine-jquery

I'm trying to test a bit of JavaScript using jasmine & jasmine-jquery

So I have this bit of Javascript in function

```
trackTransition = ()->
  $("#test").on "transitionend MSTransitionEnd webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd", ()-> 
    console.log "trans End"
```

I've applied some styes in spec.css that add a css transition and added some html into a fixture, then added in the jasmine specs like so:

```
   describe "Checks when animation finished", ->
      beforeEach ->
        @trans = spyOnEvent('#test', 'transitionend MSTransitionEnd webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd')
        jasmine.Clock.useMock()
        trackTransition()

      it "Should check when transition ended", ->
        expect(@trans).not.toHaveBeenTriggered()
        jasmine.Clock.tick(1001)
        expect(@trans).toHaveBeenTriggered()
```

Now I have tested this on the page and fires fine, but on runner it fails and even the console.log doesn't run. Can you test the transitions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This cant  work cause `jasmine.Clock` doesn't change the time or make the test to wait for 1000ms. It just overwrites `window.setTimeout`. So whenever you call `setTimeout(someFunction, 1000)` it saved the passed functions and times. Then when you call `tick` it just calls any saved functions with a time lower then the you passed to the `tick` call.

So the only way to test your transitionEnd event is to trigger the event manually. Also it makes not much sense to test that the event is fired after a specific time, as this is a browser behavior you rely on.

Comment: Ah ok thanks, tbh it's the function it triggers, but maybe I'll just test the function in isolation.